# What skills does it take to develop an Android app?

Tags: java, android, mobile

What skills does it take to develop an Android app?

How easy is it to publish one in the app market?

Does it need any previous experience?

This question serves as a personal to-do list on what to learn. I would like to develop an Android app in the near future.

Comment: This question is way too broad. One important thing when doing anything is "do your research". And that's **you** doing the research, not asking for a TODO list from others.

Comment: This question will be closed, but you should start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html that's the best and only starting point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  What skills does it take to develop an Android app?
```

You must have core knowledge of JAVA to start android development and a having good knowledge of xml,layouts designing,Database implementation and SQL Queries.

```
 How easy is it to publish one in the app market?
```

Check out the [Step by Step Explanation of Pusblishing Application on Market](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/)  and also [Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html)

```
Does it need any previous experience?
```

Its not necessary but having a bit knowledge of Android would be more better and Core knowledge of JAVA is enough.

```
If you would like to develop an Android app in the near future.
```

I suggest you to start with [Getting Started in Android](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

First thing to build an android app

You should have good skills in java,classes,XMl user interface

You should have good knowledge of database its functions and queries.

One should be hardworking and dedicated for work

These all points are enough to build an app in android